# DateTime value is different across different versions of .NET framework

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, .net-4.0, .net-3.5

I have a service(Language: VB.NET, Framework:.NET 3.5) that returns a dataset from which I read a date. The value of the column in the database is: "1980-03-30 00:00:00.000".

In a client(Language: C#) that uses .NET 3.5, the value is coming thorough as : 3/30/1980 12:00:00 AM

However, when I change the same client to use .NET 4 or .NET 4.5, the date which comes through the service is: 3/29/1980 11:00:00 PM

Comment: What exact code is being used to read the DateTime's?

Comment: datetime is dependant on specific locale - ensure that it is unchanged during your tests

Comment: I read the date directly from the dataset as follows:
Convert.ToDateTime(client.Tables[0].Rows[0]["BIRTHDATE"]);

Comment: The dataset is the one that is being passed from the service to client. I'm starting to wonder if Serialization causes the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference in `DateTime` values is not because of .Net framework, its because of the locale settings.

Never pass `DateTime` values through your web service, pass [`DateTimeOffset`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and then convert to `DateTime` type in your client.

Comment: I'm not passing a DateTime object. It's a part of the dataset.

Comment: @AshishShakya, [returning DataSet is bad](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1659402/to-return-a-dataset-in-a-web-service-or-not) but its probably off topic here, You have to modify your DataSet and return a column of `DateTimeOffset` type, created from the original `DateTime` object, and use that.

Comment: The web service is setup to just call a stored procedure and returns the result to the client. In the database, the column is a `DateTime`. I do not have the option of changing how the value is stored in the database at this point. I can read the dataset and transform the datetime to datetimeoffset and pass a processed dataset back to the client. However, is there any thing else that will solve the issue?

Comment: @AshishShakya, I don't know of any other way, I had this issue once and I end up returning `DateTimeOffset` column instead of `DateTime`, You can get the `DateTimeOffset` in your proc see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2008522/sql-server-datetime-to-datetimeoffset) or modify the `DataSet` in your web service before sending.

Comment: Thank you @Habib. I'll try out your suggestions.